# Maven assembly plugin dependency jars are missing

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a problem using maven assembly plugin when trying to create a distributable archive. Everything is
working ok except some dependency jars are missing from the archive lib directory.  For example hamcrest-core.jar, xnio-nio-3.3.6.Final.jar, objenesis-2.5.jar and few other jars are not not added.Is there any reason not to be included? The maven-dependency-plugin includes all the dependency jars inside the target/lib and it's ok.

Here is what I have inside my pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/lib
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>online-store</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>com.online.store.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And here is what I have in assembly.xml

```
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
   <id>online-store</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <!-- some file sets -->
    </fileSets>    
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
        <scope>compile</scope>  
        <includes>
                    <include>*:jar:*</include>
            </includes>
        <outputDirectory>/online-store/lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Which scope have dependencies that are not included? In the assembly file you are indicating that only those of the scope provided

Comment: It's scope test. How can I change the scope to include them also?

Comment: You can include another dependencySet with scope test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include another dependencySet with scope test.

For example:

```
<assembly> 
    ...
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
        <scope>compile</scope>  
        <includes>
               <include>*:jar:*</include>
            </includes>
        <outputDirectory>/online-store/lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
        <scope>test</scope> 
        <includes>
               <include>*:jar:*</include>
            </includes>
        <outputDirectory>/online-store/lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```